# JavaFX LoadException but Everything Looks Perfect

Tags: java, javafx

I have some code, straight from the Java 8 textbook.  My assignment is to edit the code, but I can't get the base code to run.
Files include TipCalculator.java, TipCalculatorController.java, and TipCalculator.fxml

I am not looking for help with the actual assignment.  Just a tip on how to get the code to not error out.

I get the same error in Eclipse Photon and Neon.

I am making a new > project > JavaFX Project in Eclipse.

The LoadException shows line 12, which is the @Override line, but it shows the TipCalculator.fxml file path correctly placed in the project.  Yes, the .fxml file is copied in the application area.  I tried all the variations to  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("TipCalculator.fxml")); that I could find.  Nothing gets rid of the errors.  And since it is straight from the book, I wouldn't think it would need any alterations.
My only variation from the book code is "package application" at the top of my .java files.  The book code did not have that, but it automatically pops up in my application classes.

TipCalculator.java

```
package application;

//Fig. 12.19: TipCalculator.java
//Main application class that loads and displays the Tip Calculator's GUI.
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TipCalculator extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
   Parent root = 
      FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("TipCalculator.fxml"));

   Scene scene = new Scene(root); // attach scene graph to scene
   stage.setTitle("Tip Calculator"); // displayed in window's title bar
   stage.setScene(scene); // attach scene to stage
   stage.show(); // display the stage
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   // create a TipCalculator object and call its start method
   launch(args); 
}
}


/**************************************************************************
* (C) Copyright 1992-2018 by Deitel & Associates, Inc. and               *
* Pearson Education, Inc. All Rights Reserved.                           *
*                                                                        *
* DISCLAIMER: The authors and publisher of this book have used their     *
* best efforts in preparing the book. These efforts include the          *
* development, research, and testing of the theories and programs        *
* to determine their effectiveness. The authors and publisher make       *
* no warranty of any kind, expressed or implied, with regard to these    *
* programs or to the documentation contained in these books. The authors *
* and publisher shall not be liable in any event for incidental or       *
* consequential damages in connection with, or arising out of, the       *
* furnishing, performance, or use of these programs.                     *
*************************************************************************/
```

TipCalculatorController.java

```
package application;

//TipCalculatorController.java
//Controller that handles calculateButton and tipPercentageSlider events
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class TipCalculatorController { 
// formatters for currency and percentages
private static final NumberFormat currency = 
   NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
private static final NumberFormat percent = 
   NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();

private BigDecimal tipPercentage = new BigDecimal(0.15); // 15% default

// GUI controls defined in FXML and used by the controller's code
@FXML 
private TextField amountTextField; 

@FXML
private Label tipPercentageLabel; 

@FXML
private Slider tipPercentageSlider;

@FXML
private TextField tipTextField;

@FXML
private TextField totalTextField;

// calculates and displays the tip and total amounts
@FXML
private void calculateButtonPressed(ActionEvent event) {
   try {
      BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(amountTextField.getText());
      BigDecimal tip = amount.multiply(tipPercentage);
      BigDecimal total = amount.add(tip);

      tipTextField.setText(currency.format(tip));
      totalTextField.setText(currency.format(total));
   }
   catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
      amountTextField.setText("Enter amount");
      amountTextField.selectAll();
      amountTextField.requestFocus();
   }
}

// called by FXMLLoader to initialize the controller
public void initialize() {
   // 0-4 rounds down, 5-9 rounds up 
   currency.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

   // listener for changes to tipPercentageSlider's value
   tipPercentageSlider.valueProperty().addListener(
      new ChangeListener<Number>() {
         @Override
         public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, 
            Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            tipPercentage = 
               BigDecimal.valueOf(newValue.intValue() / 100.0);
            tipPercentageLabel.setText(percent.format(tipPercentage));
         }
      }
   );
}
}

/**************************************************************************
* (C) Copyright 1992-2018 by Deitel & Associates, Inc. and               *
* Pearson Education, Inc. All Rights Reserved.                           *
*                                                                        *
* DISCLAIMER: The authors and publisher of this book have used their     *
* best efforts in preparing the book. These efforts include the          *
* development, research, and testing of the theories and programs        *
* to determine their effectiveness. The authors and publisher make       *
* no warranty of any kind, expressed or implied, with regard to these    *
* programs or to the documentation contained in these books. The authors *
* and publisher shall not be liable in any event for incidental or       *
* consequential damages in connection with, or arising out of, the       *
* furnishing, performance, or use of these programs.                     *
*************************************************************************/
```

TipCalculator.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Slider?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<GridPane hgap="8.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="TipCalculatorController">
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints halignment="RIGHT" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
   </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Label text="Amount" />
      <Label fx:id="tipPercentageLabel" text="15%" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <Label text="Tip" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <Label text="Total" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
      <TextField fx:id="amountTextField" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
      <TextField fx:id="tipTextField" editable="false" focusTraversable="false" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <TextField fx:id="totalTextField" editable="false" focusTraversable="false" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
      <Slider fx:id="tipPercentageSlider" blockIncrement="5.0" max="30.0" value="15.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <Button maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#calculateButtonPressed" text="Calculate" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="14.0" left="14.0" right="14.0" top="14.0" />
   </padding>
</GridPane>
```

StackTrace

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Carl/workspace2/TipCalculatorAttempt5/bin/application/TipCalculator.fxml:12

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:922)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at application.TipCalculator.start(TipCalculator.java:15)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TipCalculatorController
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:920)
    ... 22 more
Exception running application application.TipCalculator
```

Comment: try in the FXML file "fx:controller="application.TipCalculatorController""

Comment: That solved it for me!  Thank you so much!  I did see that in previous posts, but I didn't see fx:controller in my own fxml file.  It was far to the right.